# Why number sign ignore in url?

Tags: web-services, rest, url, filter, jersey

I should develop a web service with rest by jersey to parse below url:
http://localhost:8080/userApp/processMsg/request?Username=$username&LastName=$lastName&Message=$Message&SessionId=$sessionId

I used below code and worked properly:

```
@POST
@Path("/request")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8")
public UserResponse getUsers(@QueryParam("Username") String Username,
                               @QueryParam("LastName") String LastName,
                               @QueryParam("Message") String Message,
                               @QueryParam("SessionId") String SessionId
) {

    // my code
}
```

My problem is when I there is '#' character in the url, in this case, from this character to end of the url, will be ignored. I can't make any changes to url format and # sign always exist at the end of message field.
for avoiding this, I added a filter to my web.xml, with this code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       next)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // Respect the client-specified character encoding
    // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
    if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);


    /**
     * Set the default response content type and encoding
     */
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");


    next.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

but the value of request.getParameterMap() was same of the previous,and there isn't end of the url. for example when I have in url:
http://localhost:8080/userApp/processMsg/request?Username=$test&LastName=$test2&Message=$HelloWorld#&SessionId=$123456, what my application received in url, is :
http://localhost:8080/userApp/processMsg/request?Username=$test&LastName=$test2&Message=$HelloWorld

how can I handle this problem?

Comment: did you get it to work? if so, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

pound (#) sign is reserved character in a URL. You need to URL encode it.

http://someurl?Message=$HelloWorld%23&otherParam

http://localhost:8080/userApp/processMsg/request?Username=$test&LastName=$test2&Message=$HelloWorld%23&SessionId=$123456

the pound sign is used for "anchor".

Spaces, and other special characters all need to be URL Encoded